# binarySearch collections using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm sorry for the stupid question, I have been searching about how to use binarysearch with my ArrayList like this :

```
List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();       
        arrList.add(3); 
        arrList.add(5); 
        arrList.add(7);
        arrList.add(2);
```

The problem is when I use :

```
Collections.sort(arrList);
Collections.reverse(arrList);
int indeks = Collections.binarySearch(arrList, 7);
```

the value of indeks is always -5, I thought it should be 2 because after reversing myArrList the output looks like this :

```
[7, 5, 3, 2]
```

So what should I do here in order to get the right indeks of 7...?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the javadoc of `binarySearch` say?

Comment: mmmm.. .I didn't read it ... :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collections.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) expects elements to be in ascending order:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the `sort(List)` method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

If you want to do a binary search on a descending list, use [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--):

```
int indeks = Collections.binarySearch(arrList, 7, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

`indeks` is now 0, corresponding to the first element of the list.

Note that you can use the same comparator to sort the list descending, instead of sorting ascending and then reversing:

```
Collections.sort(arrList, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Shmosel... :)

Answer (score 0):

`binarySearch()` results are undefined if the list is not sorted in **ascending** order. By reversing your list, it's sorted in descending order, hence the results you're seeing.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-):

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural
>   ordering of its elements (as by the `sort(List)` method) prior to making
>   this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr.Robby.. :)